# Polish spaces, closed sets and $G_{\delta}$ sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In a series of lecture notes regarding descriptive set theory, in the section regarding the Borel hierarchy I found the following statement:

> *We will restrict ourselves from now on to Polish spaces, to ensure that every closed set is a countable intersection of open sets.*

Then, there is a reference to an exercise that should explain this statement, but that I did not actually find.

Thus, to be explicit, my problem is the following: why, by restricting to Polish spaces, we ensure that every closed set is a countable intersection of open sets?

Is there somebody who can enlighten me?

As always, any feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for you time and help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: My problem is mainly why restricting our attention to Polish spaces we get that every closed set is a countable intersection of open sets?

Comment: Kolmin, can you prove this for a (closed) interval in $\mathbb R$? How about a (closed) circle in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: If you already start in metric spaces, there is no need for going to Polish spaces for this, as it already holds in all metric spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working in a Polish space $X$, take any compatible metric $d$ and now given a closed set $A$ define $A_n=\{x\in X\mid\exists a\in A:d(a,x)<\frac1n\}$.

It's not hard to see that $A_n=\bigcup\{B(a,\frac1n)\mid a\in A\}$, so it is an open set. And now $A=\bigcap A_n$. One inclusion is immediate, the other follows from the fact that $A$ is closed in a metric space (given $x$ in the intersection, find a sequence of elements from $A$ which converges to $x$).

Comment: The remark is in fact misleading: in every metric space a cloed set is a countable intersection of open sets, this does not need completeness, or separability, at all. It suffices to consider metric spaces, if you just want that property (or just perfectly normal spaces, which is a larger class).

Comment: Valid remark. I removed the offending "complete" condition!

Comment: It's in fact misleading in the original question, is what I meant.

Comment: Well, I somewhat agree. Polish spaces, however, are important for descriptive set theory, and this is *one* of the reasons for that.

Comment: First of all, thanks to Asaf Karagila for the answer. Then, thanks to Henno Brandsma for the comment, both to the original question and to this answer. Considering this question has not been particularly well received (it has been considered off-topic by two users), and Henno Brandsma in a previous comment referred to what I wrote in the original questions as misleading, I wanted to explain that I simply asked quite literally what I found originally in those lecture notes. Thus, I did try to force the question to a clear-cut one, because as I wrote it initially (and Asaf Karagila pointed out)

Comment: ...was kind of broad, but still mine was an attempt to force the lack of understanding of a specific passage, in a specific answer. By doing so, I am afraid I wrote something misleading due to my lack of math sophistication, but still the all problem was that I simply did not understand the implications of the statments. The same implications I know start to see by the last comment of Asaf Karagila to this very same answer. :)